# node+express: linking uploaded files to the respective user

Tags: node.js, express

What would be the best way to attach file uploads to the user that uploaded them?

I was thinking I would create a mongoose model for file uploads with a schema like this:

```
user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
url: String
```

where the url is simply the location of the file uploaded. However, will this scale well?

Is there a more standard way to do something like this?

Comment: You would do it the same way that you handle any other one to many relationship in a database. Nothing overly special about file uploads that would change that.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reassurance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I would do it. In addition, you can set a `pre('save')` function to set `user` to whomever uploaded the image.